# Force https and non-www urls, not working in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the `public_html` folder which is the root folder of my main site `thesite.com`, I have this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.thesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.thesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thesite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thesite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1&sid=$2&did=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2&vid=$3&mid=$4 [L]                                                
RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2&vid=$3 [L]                                                                
RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^offer/(.*) product_offer.php?ind=$1


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Here, am forcing non-www url as well as forcing `https` URL for the `thesite.com`. And I have two subdomains: `m.thesite.com` and `blog.thesite.com`. 
Both are in separate subfolders inside `public_html`.

The `m.thesite.com` is in `/public_html/m.thesite.com/` folder. And it has this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.m\.thesite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.zapteka.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1&sid=$2&did=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ category\_product\_list.php?mid=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2&vid=$3&mid=$4 [L]                                                
RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2&vid=$3 [L]                                                                
RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]     

RewriteRule ^offer/(.*) product_offer.php?ind=$1
```

For this subdomain also, I need to force https urls as well as non-www urls.

It seems to be working for the main site. I mean `thesite.com`. But when I try to access the `m.thesite.com`, it seems to be internally redirecting to the files of `thesite.com` instead of the `m.thesite.com`. I mean the url is being shown as `https://m.thesite.com/` but the pages are from `https://thesite.com`

I have been trying to debug the issue for several hours now. Probably it could be something small that I missed. Any ideas?

BTW, `thesite.com` is having Wildcard SSL installed.

**EDIT**

Am sorry if my explanation was confusing. When I said url is showing as `https://m.thesite.com/` but the content is from `https://thesite.com/`, I meant to say that in browser the url is shown as `https://m.thesite.com`. But the template file contents where from the desktop version of the main site `thesite.com`. The `m.thesite.com` is mobile version of the site. The pages that displays the contents where separate in both the desktop and mobile version of the site.

Like you see in the htaccess code that I included above, there is some PHP files inside the `/public_html/` folder for the desktop version. All the files for the mobile version of the site is in `/public_html/m.thesite.com/` folder.

So, in short, when I try to access the `https://m.thesite.com/`, it is displaying the `index.php` page from `/public_html/index.php` instead of `/public_html/m.thesite.com/`

So that's how I found that there's issue in the routing.

**EDIT**

VirtualHost entries fetched by using this command `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -S`:

[image]

I have also checked the Apache version and saw that it's `2.2.27` using the command: `httpd -V`

So I tried adding this line in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteLog "/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

But it was giving internal server error. So I tried this line instead also:

```
LogLevel mod_rewrite.c:trace8
```

That was also giving me internal server error when site is accessed. So I commented it out.

Comment: @anubhava, Sorry if I was confusing. I have edited the question and explained about it. Please check.

Comment: hmm can you tell me where to look for it in cPanel? Is it accessible from cPanel?

Comment: I do not know cpanel well, but does it show what is `DocumentRoot` of mobile site? Also what is full URL you are entering in browser?

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is by default the `index.php` in that current directory. To access the site, I just type `m.thesite.com` in the Chrome address bar.

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is a directory not a file. You will need help from server admin to enable `RewriteLog` and provide the output from that log here for further debugging.

Comment: Oh sorry. Misread as `DirectoryIndex`. Okay I will check it. Let me contact the hosting provider

Comment: I checked the error_log file of the server and saw this line `RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.thesite.com' does NOT match server name!?` Does it has any effect on our issue? I don't see the `RewriteLog` file there. So probably it's not enabled. I have emailed the hosting provider to enable it.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the VirtualHost entries. Any ideas? Also saw this link from Bluehost(this site is in a VPS server): https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/766